# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "history/lib/DOMStateStorage"

Tags: reactjs, react-boilerplate

I am trying to run a react project on local but I get this error on the console:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "history/lib/DOMStateStorage"
>       at webpackMissingModule (StateStorage.js:5)

any idea, to solve it?

Comment: Add your webpack file, check your dependencies that are correctly installed

Comment: I did check them.

Comment: Paste webpack file